# Multiplying Row.values and user input values in Reactjs tables

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table that gets data(wages/hr & numberofPresentAttendances) from the backend database. I'm trying to create a UI inside the same table that allows the user to input values(Nos of overtime hours), which is then automatically used to compute totalWages = (wages/hr.numberofPresentAttendances.overtime).

```
 filtered = this.state.data.map( (row, i) => {
      if(row.department.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.departmentFilter) > -1){
        return (
          <tr key={"workerData"+i}>
            <td>{i+1}</td>

            <td>{row.name}</td>
            <td>{row.numberofPresentAttendances}</td>
           <td>{row.wages}</td>
           <td>{row.totalWages}</td>
            <td>{row.overtime}</td>
            <td>overtime</td>
                <td>
                  <input number="text" name="overtime" id="time" className="form-control" 
                  placeholder="Enter Nos of overtime hrs..." 
                  value={this.state.overtime} 
                  onChange={this.handleOvertimeChange} required />
                </td>
            <td>{row.Tallowance}</td>

            <td>


            </td>
          </tr>
```

I know this is not the right way to do this but I would like to do something like this :

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {

      totalWages:0,

    };


    this.onOvertimeChange = this.onOvertimeChange.bind(this);
  }
```

```
onOvertimeChange(event){
    this.setState({ totalWages: event.target.value*row.wages*row.numberofPresentAttendances });
  }
```

If done this way, I will get several errors, one of the errors will be "Row not defined"
How do I get it to work so that it works on each row?

Answer (score 0):

The function doesn't know what row is, pass it as an argument and create a closure on the `onOvertimeChange` function

```
...
                  onChange={this.handleOvertimeChange(row)} required />
...
```

and Update onOvertimeChange as below

```
const onOvertimeChange = (row) => (event) => {
    this.setState({ totalWages: event.target.value*row.wages*row.numberofPresentAttendances });
  }
```

Comment: @Dhanajai great info, however, another issue I am having is that "Row.totalWages'' is not having access to its value in the state, and I still can't figure out how to access the state within the <td> tag